# Forms Authenticated Web APIs and jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

I have an issue that I am seriously struggling with.

I have a website, and a separate WebAPI which I want to be able to authenticate against each other. I was thinking that forms authentication would be best here. However, on my website, how do I go about calling the forms authenticated webAPI via a jQuery AJAX call?

Does anyone have any links or suggestions?

Comment: you seperate your website with your web api?

Comment: yes, because they need to live on separate servers. Mainly as the API is going to be used by many other apps

Comment: Your web api actually implement Form Authentication?

Comment: i havent implemented anything yet. I am trying to work out the best approach first so I dont waste too much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion in this [blog post on mixing forms authentication and basic authentication in Web API](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/mixing-forms-authentication-basic.html). You may be able to leverage some the principles in this article although it was tested with the Web API's residing on the same server as the web application.

If you keep the Web API and web application on separate servers your web application will run into [cross domain issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) and will have to support JSONP in your Web API.  A possible work around for your website is to create a Web API locally on your web server which is just a facade to the Web API on the remote server.  You incorporate the standard security methods on the local Web API, using [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), which in turn just calls your the Web API on the remote server. You can incorporate whatever security method you want to have for external users on the remote Web API.

Comment: You *could* max Forms and Basic, or you could just share Forms across both. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, its greatly appreciated. We have decided that the facade route is going to be best. A little more overhead and complexity but it will scale in the way that we want.